# How do I change Command Prompt from C:\> to H:\> - I'm trying to install ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm very new at this, just started to learn about code

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails by Command Prompt H:>gem install rails (I already have ruby installed on my windows 7/8 laptop)

but I don't know how to change from C:> to H:>

at the moment it says: C:\WINDOWS\system32>

I'm running it as administrator

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line prompt do the following:

```
cd /d H:\
```

Comment: thankslol, I just realised I don't have a H drive, only C and D... where do I go from here??? I tried typing in gem install rails, but I get an message saying: 'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file. then again I get the line with C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: @collibri If your command prompt says 'C:\WINDOWS\system32>' and you want to change to 'C:\' then do the following: 'cd /d C:\'

Answer (score 1):

the command "C:> H:" should allow you to change drives.